Should Ubuntu include a basic permission recovery tool?
After fixing a broken system caused by accidental chown -R on /var, I noticed Ubuntu (and not just Ubuntu) lacks a basic recovery tool for critical filesystem permissions.
No major Linux distribution seems to have this basic safety feature.
Currently, when someone breaks system permissions:

Boot from Live USB and manually fix permissions
Reinstall the system
Manually hunt down and fix each critical directory

Proposal: A simple built-in tool (similar to how fsck exists for filesystem checks) that restores defaults for minimum critical directories:
fix-permissions --minimal # Just /var + critical subdirs needed to boot
fix-permissions --desktop # Add display manager dirs
fix-permissions /mnt # For Live USB recovery

I made a basic bash script that handles core /var directories. It already helped me recover from a broken GUI login without reinstalling. While package managers can fix their own permissions, there's no tool to restore basic system functionality.

Would the script referenced in the answer of verify ownership on all files and directories associated with packages do what you want?

@ChesterGillon The dpkg approach only fixes permissions for files owned by packages. The issue is about critical system directories that need specific permissions to even boot/login (like /var/lib/gdm3 needing gdm:gdm ownership).
What I'm proposing is more like a "first aid kit" - just enough permission fixes to get a basic working system, not a full system repair. Like how fsck exists alongside more comprehensive filesystem tools.

I've volunteered with a recycler which provided such a tool pre-installed on its systems; whilst it wasn't perfect or complete; it would fix many such problems, so tools do exist. They're not new, given the file-system we're using is three+ decades old & new users tend to do the same stupid things new users did 10, 20 & 30 years ago; but everyone is free to choose their own backup/recovery strategy, most not like one being forced on them (seeing it as bloat). Your question text doesn't actually involve a question, and this is a User Support Q&A site, not a dev site.

@guiverc Interesting perspective about bloat, but that raises a question - why isn't fsck considered bloat? It's forced on systems, yet accepted as a standard recovery tool. Both scenarios (filesystem corruption and broken permissions) can make a system unbootable and both are common "new user mistakes". Yet one has a standard recovery tool and the other doesn't. You mentioned you've seen such tools work successfully at a recycler. That suggests there's practical value in having them accessible, whether built-in or optional.
